# How to concatenate two strings in sql and pad one string with 0's?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two fields in a table.  One contains values such as BTA, BEA, REA.  The other contains values such as 1,2,63,103.

I want to combine the 2 fields so they look like this BTA001, BTA002, BTA063, BTA103.

Notice how if the numbers are not 3 characters in length, I want to pad some 0's to the left of the number to make it equal to 3.

How would I go about doing this?  The fields in the table are called Type which correspond to BTA, BEA, and REA and Id is the field that corresponds to 1, 2, 63, and 103.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select Type + right('00' + cast(id as varchar(10)), 3)
from ...
```

Edit: if id can be null and you would like a zero to show, you can do:

```
select Type + right('00' + cast(isnull(id, 0) as varchar(10)), 3) 
from ...
```

Comment: What is the main difference between your answer and Learning's?

Comment: Very little. I made the assumption you will always get a single-digit number out of the Id column, in which case you only need to prepend two zeros. CAST is ANSI-standard (thus portable), whereas CONVERT is SQL Server specific, but gives you more flexible conversion options.

Comment: What if the Id column can contain a null?

Comment: Depends what about you want in that case. I edited my answer to provide an option. You may actually not want those rows at all in which case you should exclude them in the where clause

Answer (score 1):

select
  C1 + right(('000' + cast(C2 as nvarchar(10)),3) as

from t1

Answer (score 1):

select FIELD1 + RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,FIELD2), 3)

Comment: What is the difference between your implementation and OrbMan's?